# After manually fail over resume button is disabled and query doesn't resumes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-mirroring

As there is no witess available, so when resumes the mirrored database by

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name> SET PARTNER RESUME;
```

does not resumes the mirroring. Resume button is also disabled. I don't get any error. What is the checkpoint?

Comment: i voted to move to dba.stack because i think you'll get better traction there.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll consider to move there.